# How to add multiple strings into one array?

Tags: php

In a foreach, I have one big long string in a variable that is similar to:

```
apple banana orange pear
```

What I have tried is

```
$fruitArray = explode(' ', $fruitVariable);
```

But what I end up with is MULTIPLE arrays when I only want one:

```
Array
(
    [0] => apple
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => banana
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => orange
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => pear
    [1] => 
)
```

When what I'm looking for is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => apple
    [1] => banana
    [2] => orange
    [3] => pear
)
```

I've done this before but I just can't remember how I did this in the past.

Comment: Need to show your actual code, `foreach` and what's inside it.

Comment: `explode` will always produce only one array. If you're getting multiple arrays, it has to be because of something that isn't shown here.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Referring to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.explode.php) function `explode` can also return a boolean value "false". However, this doesn't change anything here.

Comment: @Robson well, that's true. One or zero arrays, then. But still, not more than one.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems to be correct.
May be your missing something else. The code works perfectly fine.

```
<?php

$fruits = 'apple banana orange pear';
$fruitsArray = explode(' ', $fruits);
print_r ($fruitsArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems to be correct:

```
<?php
$fruitVariable = "apple banana orange pear";
$fruitArray = explode(' ', $fruitVariable);
var_dump($fruitArray);
```

The output is:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "apple"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "banana"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "orange"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "pear"
}
```

Here you can run the code: http://ideone.com/rCnz7G

Maybe you have some extra (invisible?) whitespaces in your string?

Comment: Having extra spaces in the string would cause the result to have extra entries for the extra spaces, but it would not result in multiple arrays. There has to be something else going on there.

Comment: @Don'tPanic On a basis of given information, I confirmed that the approach presented in the question was correct. If the author of the question will be able to add some details, then I'll try to complete my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $a = "one";
 $b = "two";
 $c = "three";
 $d = "four";
 $data = ['first'=>$a,'sec'=>$b,'third'=>$c,];
 print_r($data);
```

The output is:

```
Array ( [first] => one [sec] => two [third] => three )
```

Comment: This (more than a year old) question asks about an array with numeric indices